# Wordpress database update - suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code which was working but now for some reason does not.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['website'])){$dbfields['website'] = $_REQUEST['website'];};
if(isset($_REQUEST['email'])){$dbfields['email'] = $_REQUEST['email'];};
$where = array( 'ID' => $_REQUEST['ID'] );
$result = $wpdb->update($this->the_table, $dbfields, $where);
return $result;
```

The result object should return 2, but now returns 0 suggesting that the values are the same.
Whatever I set the values to, the db is not updated and a result of 0 is returned.

Is there any way of finding what query is being generated by the wpdb object. Unfortunately, I have no real ability to properly debug php on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows

> Update a row in the table. Returns false if errors, or the number of rows affected if successful.

The 0 (or false) most probably indicates an error has occurred. I suggest you [enable debug mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) though be prepared to sift through all the errors from the Wordpress core and any other plugins you have installed.

Also, unless `ID` is not a primary key, I'd only expect your update to return at most one result.

Comment: Thanks Phil. It seems suddenly I need to cast the id correctly. I was passing the id as a string knowing it was really a bigint. This was previously ok. I've isolated the problem at least.

Comment: My next question is how to cast a string to a number in php. Should be easy. I'll google it.